# Await don't work with migrateasync()

Tags: c#, xamarin, entity-framework-core

I'm learning Entity Framework and Xamarin right now, and trying to write simple to-do list with database connection. I found and copied this code for database connection, but my IDE (Visual Studio 2017) output error, saying that await works only with methods with async modifier. I tried to find some solutions here, but wasn't able to find it. What might cause this issues and what possible fixes are?

```
var dbFolder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
var fileName = "Tasks.db";
var dbFullPath = dbFolder+"\\"+fileName;
mainContext = new TaskContext(dbFullPath);
await mainContext.Database.MigrateAsync();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should read about async/await https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/hh191443(v=vs.120). Doing so, you will figure out that if you include the `async` modifier after the access modifier (`public`, `private`, etc.) of the corresponding method this would be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The `async` modifier isn't the "Async" at the end of "MigrateAsync" - that's just a naming convention. What the compiler is telling you is that the method *in which you call `await`* is the one that shuold be marked async.

You didn't bring the whole method, only the code snippet, but it has to be a method marked as `async` and returning `void` or a `Task`:

```
public async void Migrate()
{
    var dbFolder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    var fileName = "Tasks.db";
    var dbFullPath = dbFolder+"\\"+fileName;
    mainContext = new TaskContext(dbFullPath);
    await mainContext.Database.MigrateAsync();
}
```

This is because calling `await` affects the *calling* method, not the called method. It makes the enveloping `Migrate` method stop its execution, returns control to the caller, and build the behind-the-scenes state machine to resume execution. It's the caller that's an async method.

I suggest going over the basic tutorials for async/await, because it's *critical* that you understand how they're used. Just copy-pasting a random code snippet is no way to get things to work:

- [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/hh191443(v=vs.120))

Comment: An async method should never return void, except it being an event handler.